# Would POSIXct or Lubridate work on this?

Tags: r, posixct, lubridate

I got a date from `searchTwitter` function from TwitteR package, and I have a very hard time of converting it to MM/DD/YYYY. I have tried `POSIXct` and `lubridate` but none is working. I would like to seek your help to show me what I did wrong.

The date that I receive from Twitter  as follow :

```
[1] 1408642144 1408642135 1408642110 1408642091 1408642038 1408642036 1408642035
```

I've tried the `POSIXct` function as :

```
r_stats_created <- sapply(r_stats,function (x) as.POSIXct(x$getCreated(),origin="1970-01-01"))
```

But nothing work, it gave me the same result as I had before :

```
head(r_stats_created)
[1] 1408642144 1408642135 1408642110 1408642091 1408642038 1408642036 1408642035
```

It did not convert to MM/DD/YYYY as I wish. So please help me to show me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Works as is:

```
R> vec <- c(1408642144, 1408642135, 1408642110, 1408642091, 1408642038, 
+           1408642036, 1408642035)
R> as.POSIXct(vec, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2014-08-21 12:29:04 CDT" "2014-08-21 12:28:55 CDT" "2014-08-21 12:28:30 CDT" 
[4] "2014-08-21 12:28:11 CDT" "2014-08-21 12:27:18 CDT" "2014-08-21 12:27:16 CDT"
[7] "2014-08-21 12:27:15 CDT"
R>
```

You don't need `sapply()` as these calls are already vectorized, and you don't want `getCreated()` as that implies a function call.